# connect to other computer that is not local

Tags: c#, multithreading

I try to connect from my pc to other pc what I have at home and both are connected to the internet. So I check the other pc with the program MyIpAdress and it is like: `38.xx.xx.xx.`
And I have this program:The server:

```
public delegate void StatusChangedHandler(object sender, StatusChangedEventArgs e);

    public class StatusChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        // This will store our only parameter / event argument, which is the event message
        private string EventMsg;

        // We need to define this property in order to retrieve the message in the event handler, back in Form1.cs
        public string EventMessage
        {
            get
            {
                return EventMsg;
            }
        }

        // The constructor will set the message
        public StatusChangedEventArgs(string strEventMsg)
        {
            EventMsg = strEventMsg;
        }
    }

    class Monitor
    {
        // Will store the IP address passed to it
        IPAddress ipAddress;

        // The constructor sets the IP address to the one retrieved by the instantiating object
        public Monitor(IPAddress address)
        {
            ipAddress = address;
        }

        // Declare the event that we'll fire later
        public event StatusChangedHandler StatusChangedEvent;
        // The thread that will hold the connection listener
        private Thread thrListener;
        // The TCP object that listens for connections
        private TcpListener tlsServer;
        // The thread that will send information to the client
        private Thread thrSender;
        // Will tell the while loop to keep monitoring for connections
        bool ServRunning = false;

        public void StartMonitoring()
        {
            // Get the IP of the first network device, however this can prove unreliable on certain configurations
            IPAddress ipaLocal = ipAddress;
            if (tlsServer == null)
            {
                // Create the TCP listener object using the IP of the server and the specified port
                tlsServer = new TcpListener(ipaLocal, 1986  );
            }
            // Start the TCP listener and listen for connections
            tlsServer.Start();

            // The while loop will check for true in this before checking for connections
            ServRunning = true;

            // Start the new tread that hosts the listener
            thrListener = new Thread(KeepListening);
            thrListener.Start();
        }

        private void KeepListening()
        {
            TcpClient tclServer;
            // While the server is running
            while (ServRunning == true)
            {
                // Accept a pending connection
                tclServer = tlsServer.AcceptTcpClient();
                // Start a new thread where our new client who just connected will be managed
                thrSender = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(AcceptClient));
                // The thread calls the AcceptClient() method
                thrSender.Start(tclServer);
            }
        }

        // Occures when a new client is accepted
        private void AcceptClient(object newClient)
        {
            // Set the argument/parameter to a message explaining what just happened
            StatusChangedEventArgs evArg = new StatusChangedEventArgs("A client was successfully accepted.");
            // Fire the event because a new client was accepted
            StatusChangedEvent(this, evArg);
        }
    }
```

But if I fill in in the textbox the ipadress: `38.xxx.xxx.xx`,
I will get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException'
>   occurred in System.dll
>   Additional information: The requested address is not valid in its context

So it can only see Local ipAdresses?
But how to change it, that it also finds not local Ipadresses?

And this is the client application:

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

```
    private string UserName = "Unknown";
    private StreamWriter swSender;
    private StreamReader srReceiver;
    private TcpClient tcpServer;
    // Needed to update the form with messages from another thread
    private delegate void UpdateLogCallback(string strMessage);
    // Needed to set the form to a "disconnected" state from another thread
    private delegate void CloseConnectionCallback(string strReason);
    private Thread thrMessaging;
    private IPAddress ipAddr;
    private bool Connected;

    public Form1()
    {
        Application.ApplicationExit += new EventHandler(OnApplicationExit);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // If we are not currently connected but awaiting to connect
        if (Connected == false)
        {
            // Initialize the connection
            InitializeConnection();
        }
        else // We are connected, thus disconnect
        {
            CloseConnection("Disconnected at user's request.");
        }
    }

    private void ReceiveMessages()
    {
        // Receive the response from the server
        srReceiver = new StreamReader(tcpServer.GetStream());
        // If the first character of the response is 1, connection was successful
        string ConResponse = srReceiver.ReadLine();
        // If the first character is a 1, connection was successful
        if (ConResponse[0] == '1')
        {
            // Update the form to tell it we are now connected
            this.Invoke(new UpdateLogCallback(this.UpdateLog), new object[] { "Connected Successfully!" });
        }
        else // If the first character is not a 1 (probably a 0), the connection was unsuccessful
        {
            string Reason = "Not Connected: ";
            // Extract the reason out of the response message. The reason starts at the 3rd character
            Reason += ConResponse.Substring(2, ConResponse.Length - 2);
            // Update the form with the reason why we couldn't connect
            this.Invoke(new CloseConnectionCallback(this.CloseConnection), new object[] { Reason });
            // Exit the method
            return;
        }
        // While we are successfully connected, read incoming lines from the server
        while (Connected)
        {
            // Show the messages in the log TextBox
            this.Invoke(new UpdateLogCallback(this.UpdateLog), new object[] { srReceiver.ReadLine() });
        }
    }
    private void InitializeConnection()
    {
        // Parse the IP address from the TextBox into an IPAddress object
        ipAddr = IPAddress.Parse(txtServerIP.Text);
        // Start a new TCP connections to the chat server
        tcpServer = new TcpClient();
        tcpServer.Connect(IPAddress.Any, 1986);

        // Helps us track whether we're connected or not
        Connected = true;
        // Prepare the form
        UserName = txtUserName.Text;

        // Disable and enable the appropriate fields
        txtServerIP.Enabled = false;
        txtUserName.Enabled = false;
        txtMessage.Enabled = true;
        btnSend.Enabled = true;
        btnConnect.Text = "Disconnect";

        // Send the desired username to the server
        swSender = new StreamWriter(tcpServer.GetStream());
        swSender.WriteLine(txtUserName.Text);
        swSender.Flush();

        // Start the thread for receiving messages and further communication
        thrMessaging = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReceiveMessages));
        thrMessaging.Start();
    }
    private void UpdateLog(string strMessage)
    {
        // Append text also scrolls the TextBox to the bottom each time
        txtLog.AppendText(strMessage + "\r\n");
    }

    private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendMessage();
    }

    private void SendMessage()
    {
        if (txtMessage.Lines.Length >= 1)
        {
            swSender.WriteLine(txtMessage.Text);
            swSender.Flush();
            txtMessage.Lines = null;
        }
        txtMessage.Text = "";
    }
    // Closes a current connection
    private void CloseConnection(string Reason)
    {
        // Show the reason why the connection is ending
        txtLog.AppendText(Reason + "\r\n");
        // Enable and disable the appropriate controls on the form
        txtServerIP.Enabled = true;
        txtUserName.Enabled = true;
        txtMessage.Enabled = false;
        btnSend.Enabled = false;
        btnConnect.Text = "Connect";

        // Close the objects
        Connected = false;
        swSender.Close();
        srReceiver.Close();
        tcpServer.Close();
    }
    public void OnApplicationExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Connected == true)
        {
            // Closes the connections, streams, etc.
            Connected = false;
            swSender.Close();
            srReceiver.Close();
            tcpServer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

So I changed this line:

tcpServer.Connect(IPAddress.Any, 1986);

but If I run the server application I will get this error:

I get the same error as by the client:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The requested address is not valid in its context

Thank you

I show you two Images:This is the Server app. That works
[image]

This is the Client app, that doesnt work:
[image]

And if I change the code in the client app, like this:

tcpServer.Connect(ipAddr, 1986); Then I will get this error:

Additional information: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

But I can pin the other pc

In the client program I have this:

```
  private void InitializeConnection()
        {
            // Parse the IP address from the TextBox into an IPAddress object
            ipAddr = IPAddress.Parse(txtServerIP.Text);
            // Start a new TCP connections to the chat server
            tcpServer = new TcpClient();
            tcpServer.Connect(IPAddress.Any, 1986);

            // Helps us track whether we're connected or not
            Connected = true;
            // Prepare the form
            UserName = txtUserName.Text;

            // Disable and enable the appropriate fields
            txtServerIP.Enabled = false;
            txtUserName.Enabled = false;
            txtMessage.Enabled = true;
            btnSend.Enabled = true;
            btnConnect.Text = "Disconnect";

            // Send the desired username to the server
            swSender = new StreamWriter(tcpServer.GetStream());
            swSender.WriteLine(txtUserName.Text);
            swSender.Flush();

            // Start the thread for receiving messages and further communication
            thrMessaging = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReceiveMessages));
            thrMessaging.Start();
        }
```

what I have to change then?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I edit the post

Comment: So for cleareness. If I run the server app, it works. But If I run the client app it doesnt

Comment: I edit the post. Can you maybe show in the code what I have to change.

Comment: @X. HI can you edit my code example. Because I dont understand exactly what you mean. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to allow TCP connections on your port in the firewall for the applications on both PCs. Make sure that connections from and to the network are allowed.

Comment: somebody some suggestions? Thank you